# How can I install a npm package previously installed globally into my React Project

Tags: npm

I know that what I am about to ask is not a good practice.

I could face a lack of internet connection for a few weeks and I wanna be ready to develop without needing to import dependencies from NPM on this meanwhile. After this event I will come back to the normal good practice of downloading dependencies locally in my apps.

Back to the question... I have already installed the dependencies that I could need globally on my macbook.

How do I get a global installed package into a local project file?

For example:

How do I get `react-router`, installed globally, into my `React` project using npm?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use local-npm package.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/local-npm

It think it does what you want.

Comment: Hello! I have got into local-npm but I am kind of lost... Could you please exemplify how could I use it in an example of installing ```react-router``` from my global instance into my project using ```local-npm```?